# e-charts stop charts from resizing plot area

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have e-charts plot with 3 y-axis and 5 different graphs and if I disable some of graphs plot size changes. 
Is it possible to stop that? 
I have 2 plots on a page and want that they would be the same size always.

Answer (score 0):

You want to set the y or x axis manually instead of letting it calculate own its own:

```
option.yAxis = {
    max: 512,
    min: 0
}

option.xAxis = {
    max: 999,
    min: 100
}
```

https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/option.html#xAxis.min